# Force Imported Value as Integer

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to save values between instances of the script running.

I'm doing that by reading a text file at the beginning of the script, and then overwriting that file with the new values at the end of the script.

tracker.txt:

```
 x=1
 y=4
 z=3
```

I'm reading the script using:

```
 Get-Content "$Root\tracker.txt" | Foreach-Object{
      $Position = $_.Split("=")
      New-Variable -Name $Position[0] -Value $Position[1]
      }
```

Unfortunately my $x $y and $z variables are being interpreted as a string instead of an integer.

Looking up New-Variable parameters, it doesn't seem like I can specify the value type.

Also I tried:

```
  New-Variable -Name $Position[0] -Value [int]$Position[1]
```

And:

```
  New-Variable -Name $Position[0] -Value ($Position[1] + 0)
```

But both did not work as expected.

How can I set these variables as an integer? I'm trying to use them later in a loop and that keeps failing because the variable can't be a string.

Comment: `[int]$Position[1]` should work if you don't use `New-Variable` and just `[int]$Position[0] = $Position[1]`

Comment: If I put `Write-Output "x: $x"` right after the Foreach-Object loop it shows `x: 1` using `New-Variable -Name $Position[0] -Value $Position[1]` and `x: ` using `[int]$Position[0] = $Position[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to save values, consider using Powershell's own object serialization. That is, [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7) and `Import-Clixml` cmdlets. When an object is serialized, its contents are written on a file. In addition to values, data types are there too.

Handling multiple variables is easier, if those are stored in a collection such as a hash table. Like so,

```
# Save some values in a hash table
$myKeys =@{ "a" = 1; "b" = 2 }
$myKeys["a"]
1
# Check variable a's type. Int32 is as expected
$myKeys["a"].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                             BaseType
-------- -------- ----                             --------
True     True     Int32                            System.ValueType

# Serialize the hash table    
Export-Clixml -Path keys.xml -InputObject $myKeys

# Create a new hash table by deserializing    
$newKeys = Import-Clixml .\keys.xml

# Check contents
$newkeys["a"]
1

# Is the new a also an int32? Yes, it is
$newkeys["a"].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                             BaseType
-------- -------- ----                             --------
True     True     Int32                            System.ValueType
```

The `keys.xml` is, as expected an XML file. Check out its contents with, say, Notepad to see how the objects are stored. When working with complex objects, `-Depth` switch needs to be used. Otherwise, serialization saves only two levels of nesting, and that'll break complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, you can force it like this.

```
@'
var1=1
var2=2
'@ | out-file "$Root\tracker.txt"

Get-Content "$Root\tracker.txt" | Foreach-Object{
    $Position = $_.Split("=")
    New-Variable -Name $Position[0] -Value ([int]$Position[1])
}

$var1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

However I really like this approach.

Create a template

```
$template = @'
{name*:var1}={[int]value:1}
{name*:var2}={[int]value:2}
'@
```

Now use ConvertFrom-String and assign to $data

```
@'
test1=1
test2=2
test3=3
test4=4
test5=5
'@ | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable data
```

Let's create our variables now. Very easy to read.

```
$data | foreach {New-Variable -Name $_.name -Value $_.value}
```

Get-Variable test*

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                         
test1                          1                                                                                                                                             
test2                          2                                                                                                                                             
test3                          3                                                                                                                                             
test4                          4                                                                                                                                             
test5                          5
```

And most importantly, they are int.

```
$test1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                          
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

Putting it all together and pulling from a file

```
$template = @'
{name*:var1}={[int]value:1}
{name*:var2}={[int]value:2}
'@

Get-Content "$Root\tracker.txt" -raw | 
    ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template |
        foreach {New-Variable -Name $_.name -Value $_.value}
```

Comment: while that does work, you may find `ConvertFrom-StringData` handy for the format the OP used. it will give you an hashtable of `key=value` pairs that are pretty easy to work with. [*grin*] plus, it saves having to manage all those variable names ...

Comment: Add an answer Lee. Still same problem, they end up strings.

Comment: no need for an Answer .. the ones y'all have posted work well ... and the best _solution to the actual problem_ is the `Clixml` technique. [*grin*]

Comment: Turns out ConvertFrom-String is better suited than ConvertFrom-StringData anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I will use this:

```
(Get-Content tracker.txt) | foreach {
  invoke-expression "[int]`$$($_.split("=")[0])=$($_.split("=")[1])"
}
```

It will create three variables with type int32.